# Why is central admin time different from server time?

Tags: central-administration, date-time, timezone

I have seen this question asked before (not here) but have never seen anyone with a genuine answer, usually people provide lots of info surrounding how Sharepoint has a different timezome for each Web, User etc but that is NOT my question.

VM is setup to be on CET - (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna. This makes sense as I am in Europe. The clock currently reads 9:57 AM.

Sharepoint Central Admin just started a job at 12:57 AM. Indeed it thinks it is 12:57 AM. This, if I am not mistaken, is PST? The timezone the VM would have been using when Sharepoint was installed.

My questions then:

1) Why is Central Admin on PST not CET when my server is on CET? Is it always PST, or is it locked to the timezone selected on the server when installed? Either seems plausible but neither very acceptable.

2) How can the timezone of Sharepoint be updated short of reinstalling? Or will even that not work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 2010 Go to **http://*centraladminsite*/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx** and change in there.  This is hidden by default, but is part of the standard regional site settings.

Comment: Ah of course! For some reason I struggle to see Central Admin as a SharePoint site of its own managed using the same settings pages as any other SharePoint site. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

You can change the Central Admin Time Zone from here:

Central Admin -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications -> SharePoint Central Administration v4 (The Central Admin Web Application) -> General Settings -> Default Time Zone

Comment: I tried setting the Default Time Zone for the Central Admin application but this doesn't seem to have any effect on the scheduling of timer jobs. I rebooted the VM too. It seems like the timer service is fixed to the time zone of the machine when Sharepoint was installed?

Comment: I guess the process is more complicated than I initially thought. Have a look here:
https://blog.azaleos.com/sharepoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20

Comment: Thanks to this thread. It fixed my same kind of issue today.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint Time Zone can be changed in Site Settings->Regional Settings -> Time Zone. It normally defaults to PDT/PST. But can be set manually

Answer (score 0):

Central Admin -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications -> SharePoint Central Administration v4 (The Central Admin Web Application) -> General Settings -> Default Time Zone is not the same.

For me `http://centraladminsite/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx` is good!