# Confusion over timer job's last run time in Central Administration

Tags: 2010, central-administration, timer-jobs, job-definitions

This is creating little confusion for me. My timer job is scheduled to run between 5 am to 7 am but after a check I found the last run time is 8:32 pm ! I understand this is a daily job that runs but should not run after 7 am. Can someone explain me or is it I have misunderstood the settings?

I observed similar situation in other timer jobs as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CentralAdmin might be in a different timezone than your servers.

[Why is central admin time different from server time?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38906/why-is-central-admin-time-different-from-server-time)

Comment: Thanks MHeld. You hit the correct spot. Now the last run time show exactly as per the schedule job timings after changing the timezone in Central Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this to check if the schedule is right:

```
Get-SPTimerJob -WebApplication "http://yourWebAppUrl" | select Name, DisplayName,Schedule | where-object{$_.Name -eq "TimeJobName"} | ft -autosize
```

Myabe someone fired it manually? or maybe is it fired programmatically?

Comment: I checked using this powershell command and found the scheduled timings are correct. Nobody should have fired manually because only I have the access to the server. There is no code written to fire it programmatically. As I said earlier in my question, the situation is same for other timer jobs. The scheduled time is different from the last run time.